# Replace by removing new line character using AWK in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file:

**a.txt**

```
f1,f2,f3
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

I want to concatenate f2 and f3 by removing the newline character in f3 [ie. f2=f2.f3]and update the file. I tried the command below, but the new line character is getting inserted as well. How do I remove that part?

```
awk -F "," -v OFS=, '{$2 = $2$3;print}' abc.txt > abc.tmp && mv abc.tmp abc.txt
```

Comment: `$3` cannot contain newline. What is output of `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2 = $2$3} 1' a.txt` ?

Comment: a,bc^M,c


d,ef^M,f


g,hi^M,i

I get the ^M character

Answer (score 3):

This is due to presence of DOS line feed `\r` at the end of line.

You can use this gnu awk command with `RS` as `\r\n` to take care of that:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{$2 = $2$3} 1' a.txt

f1,f2f3,f3
a,bc,c
d,ef,f
g,hi,i
```

Alternatively, you can run `dos2unix` command before using your regular awk command:

```
dos2unix a.txt
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{$2 = $2$3} 1' a.txt
```

Comment: There is an issue with this command, the output header will be changed to "f2f3". But I require the header to be f2 . Since it is only the values that should get concatenated

Comment: @tester Replace `{$2 = $2$3}` with `NR>1 {$2 = $2$3}`. Also, you can remove the `\r` with `sub(/\r/,"",NF)`.

Comment: @tester: Thanks James. You just need a condition `NR>1` to make this change for rows 2 and onwards. Check my updated answer.